# Grunt on html css and js file 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, gruntjs, gruntfile

After fixing my css/scss compiling I'm now try to run the css on my html file, but I keep getting:

GET http://localhost:8080/dist/css/screen.css  404 (Not Found)localhost/:26

GET http://localhost:8080/source/js/modernizr.js 404 (Not Found)localhost/:28

Now, my paths on my html files is the follow:

```
<link href="dist/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type"text/javascript" src="source/js/modernizr.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? is it an html path issue? or is it a gruntfile.js issue?
something must missing from either the html or gruntFile.js

hope it makes sense

[image: this is my folder structure.]

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    config: {
            source: 'source/',
            dest: 'dist/',
            dist: './dist/'
        },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 8080,
            livereload: 35729,
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= config.source %>html',
                port: 8080
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= config.dest %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    }, 
    watch:{
         compass:{
            options: {livereload: true },
            files:['<%= config.source %>**/*.scss'],
            tasks:['compass']
        },
        css: {
            options: {livereload: true },
            files: ['<%= config.dest %>*.css'],
            tasks: []
        },
        js: {
            options: { livereload: true },
            files: ['<%= config.source %>js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint']
        },
        images: {
            options: { livereload: true },
            files: ['<%= config.source %>images/*.*']
        },
        fontsicons: {
            options: { livereload: true },
            files: ['<%= config.source %>images/icons/**/*.{svg,eot,woff,ttf,woff2,otf}']
        },
        livereload: {
              // Here we watch the files the sass task will compile to
              // These files are sent to the live reload server after sass compiles to them
              options: { livereload: true },
              files: ['<%= config.source %>html/*']
        }
    },
    compass: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'sass',
                src: ['source/sass/*.scss', '*.sass'],
                dest: 'css/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
      }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:livereload', 'watch', 'compass', ]);

grunt.registerTask('icons', ['webfont']);

};
```

Comment: how is your local web server configured?

Comment: @PavelGatnar localhost:8080 is this one you mean?

Comment: 1. what web server are you running 2. what is the root path for localhost

Comment: Not sure I understand, localhost is 8080

Answer (score 0):

To get HTTP response from http://localhost:8080 you'll need a http server running on your computer listening on port 8080. If you have no such server running, you will get always 404 error.

E.g. on Node.js the most used is Express: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm.

With this piece of code you'll get "Hello World" response on http://localhost:8080 and handle the routes /dist and /source:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'source')));

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: @user3699998 no, grunt is just a task runner

Comment: @user3699998 this script is usually located in the application root as server.js

Comment: ok, done all, created a server.js with your code, now what? how can I run the local host? of grunt correctly?

Comment: Normally `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`, in your case 'source' and 'dist'